# Google Maps - Extract coordinates of the map's center?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I'm hoping to use a Google Map in this way:
User zooms in on the location they want (using either pan & zoom or a search bar above the map) and the coordinates of the center of the map are passed down to my PHP script as either "$lat" & "$lon" OR "$coords".  If someone could find or write some code that does this I'd be elated...  Let me know if more info is needed... My understanding of JavaScript (and even PHP) is limited so please try to be as complete as you can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is going to be problematic (and virtually impossible) because the PHP code is executed server side, before the page finishes loading in the client's browser. Javascript is executed "live" as the user does things in the browser, so there really isn't an easy straightforward way to push from JS to PHP.

To properly answer the question we need to know what you want to do with the coordinate data, and where this is the whole "framework" in your app, ex:

- Do users pick a location and then send it to you and that's it?
- Do they pick several locations (ie. pushpins or something) one after another (something like 'my favorite places')
- Can you write to a DB and process the locations when they're done?

You have a few options (ordered simplest to hardest)

1. Have the user pan/zoom the map to the spot they want, then click some button and, at that point, pull the coordinates from the map and push it to some PHP script (via GET or POST)
2. Write to a database - and include a "done" button that launches a PHP script to process the data.
3. Let the user move around the map, and when they finish moving start up a little timer and refresh the page if they hold over that position for X amount of time. When you refresh the page, pass the coordinates back into the same page (via GET or POST). When you get it in PHP, do whatever you need to with the data (and recenter the map on the coordinate. This would be very annoying from a user's perspective.

Since you asked, you can get the map's center location by doing `map.getCenter()`, which returns a lat/lon pair

Comment: Thanks for responding! :)  The option I'm aiming for is indeed the easiest (#1).  I was unsure if it was possible to get this done so I haven't bothered to set up the code on my site yet but I'm currently set up with a <select> list, whose 'id' and 'name' are both "city", that passes its value to the PHP script (which is really a whole new page).  This means that as long as I can get a value for "city" in the form of "latitude, longitude" everything beyond that point will be functional :)  The user hits enter, the server is sent the coordinates, and a page is generated.

Comment: Hey, just thinking the email update for this thread might've gotten buried in your inbox... thanks

Comment: Yeah I saw your reply -- option #1 is relatively easy, just look up some examples about sending data from javascript to PHP via GET or POST (with GET the user will be able to see/manipulate the data in the address bar - so use with caution.)

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out ever since you replied but I'm hopeless... I don't know any of the syntax for Javascript or PHP and I can really only go by example, which would make this doable, BUT... I don't know how to pull coordinates from the map using map.getCenter() and I don't know how to put that data into the PHP page that the other input field ('q') is sent to.  I have a map with an unrelated <input> field below it- the <input> field works perfectly, so can you please write some code that puts the value of map.getCenter() into a second <input> field?  Pasted my code below: